# undefined method `post_up_vote_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined

I am trying to come up with upvote/downvote method in my app and I running into a no method error.

Here is my voter form:

```
<div>
  <div class= 'pull-left'>
    <div><%= link_to " ", post_up_vote_path(post), class: 'glyphicon plyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post %></div>
    <div><strong><%= post.points %></strong></div>
    <div><%= link_to " ", post_down_vote_path(post), class: 'glyphicon plyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post %></div>
 </div>
```

Here are my routes:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users
resources :users

resources :topics do
resources :posts, except: [:index] do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  post '/up-vote' => 'votes#post_up_vote', as: :up_vote
  post '/down-vote' => 'votes#post_down_vote', as: :down_vote
 end
end
get 'about' => 'welcome#about'
root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

And here is my partial call:

```
<%= render partial: 'votes/voter', locals: { post: post } %>
```

Now I don't think there is anything wrong with my partial call or my voter partial because everything works until I try to route it.

Comment: You could run bundle exec rake routes in order to know the generated rails url helpers

Comment: You need to wrap your `vote` routes in `member do`, since they are routes that take in a single `Post` object.

Comment: @JustinLicata What would that snippet of code look like?

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to change up your routes a bit.

```
resources :posts, except: [:index] do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]

  post 'upvote', on: :member
  post 'downvote', on: :member
 end
```

The reason these are member routes instead of collection routes is being they apply to a specific member of the collection of posts...a single `Post`.

Then, you will want to run the command, `rake routes` in your Terminal to see what the appropriate path methods are. It should be something like

```
upvote_post_path(:id)
```

which requires an object be passed in..so in your view you would use it like you currently are.

```
upvote_post_path(post)
```

Comment: `on: :member`, not `to: :member`.